# How do I pronounce this 「暖」 that lacks 送り仮名?

Tags: words, readings, set-phrases, okurigana

I am learning Japanese, and one of the ways I'm doing so is playing games.  I am playing "Stranger of Sword City," and I saw this exact expression, in the game:

> 何か[暖]{L}を取るものを探して彷徨ったあなたは、やがて古びた箱を見つけ出し……

I was confused by the 「暖」 in the third character.  How do you pronounce that?  Is it just 「あたた」..?  Is it 「ダン」?  I looked through various 辞書 but couldn't find a reference to the naked 漢字.  I eventually thought to ask Chat-GPT if there is a name for when a 漢字 appears without ひらがな following, and it said that, yes there is: 送り仮名抜き, and that it is often used for poetic technique.

I'm still not clear on how this is supposed to be verbalized though.

What's really going on here?  And how do you pronounce it?

Comment: Why would you think it's あなた?

Comment: @istrasci OP asked if it could be あたた, the kunyomi reading associated with あたたかい.

Comment: @Leebo:  Oops, misread that.

Comment: "I looked through various 辞書" - not, apparently, the one [actually named as such in romaji, since it's right there](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9A%96).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel -- Of course I looked at jisho.org.  I had just never heard the 訓読み used as the word itself, so I took that for the 「ダン」 I cited in the post.  Don't assume.

Comment: I don't understand. There's an entry at the top of the list, given that reading, and identifying it as a noun and giving it a definition as a separate word. *Why is that not enough information* to come to the same conclusion as in this Q&A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

暖 in this context is read だん, and it means "heat" (noun). [暖を取る](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9A%96%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8B) is a common set phrase. Since you correctly noticed it has no okurigana, you could have also checked if 暖 has a meaning as a noun on its own. 暖 is a rare word outside of this set phrase, though...

Comment: Thank you.  That's very helpful guidance.